# Riesz-Markov-Kakutani representation theorem: inverting the relation between measure and functional

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Given a locally compact Hausdorff space $X$, it is known (see e.g. Rudin's book, Theorem 6.19) that for every bounded linear functional $\Phi$ on $C_0(X)$ there exists a unique complex Borel measure $\mu$ on $X$ such that
\begin{equation}
\Phi f=\int_X f\;\mathrm{d}\mu\qquad \text{for every }f\in C_0(X).
\end{equation}
furthermore with the operator norm $\|\Phi\|$ being equal to the total variation of $\mu$.

Since the relation between $\Phi$ and $\mu$ is one-to-one, we should be able to invert the relation above in such a way to express $\mu$ in terms of $\Phi$. Naively, one would be tempted to write
\begin{equation}
\mu(B)=\Phi 1_B
\end{equation}
for every Borel subset of $X$, where $1_B$ is the indicator function of $B$. This, however, is not correct as put it here, since $1_B$ is not continuous.

My question is: how can we write, in the "simplest" possible terms, the action of $\mu$ in terms of the functional $\Phi$ uniquely associated with it? Could the relation above still be correct by extending the functional $\Phi$ to some larger space (say, $L^p(X)$) which contains indicator functions?

Comment: By Lusin's Thereom it is possible to write $\mu (B)=\lim \Phi (f_n)$ for some sequence $(f_n)$ in $C_0(X)$. But it seems to me that  you are possibly asking for  a little too much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this can be done. My source is Royden and Fitzpatrick's real analysis, $4$th edition. They discuss the real case only (and also the $C_c$ case only but that doesn't matter) so I will pretend $\psi$ is real. I'm sure the technicalities can be ironed out but they also only showed a result like this for compact $X$, where there is a more straightforward argument for proving any $\psi$ splits into positive and negative parts (to be clear, the description of $\mu$ for positive functionals is valid in the LCH case).

The point is (maybe, only in the nice cases) we can get an explicit handle on $\mu$.
If $\psi$ is a positive linear functional then the unique Radon measure we seek is the unique (uniqueness is true but not directly) measure extending: $$\mu(U):=\sup\{\psi(f):f\in C_c(X),\,0\le f\le1,\,\mathrm{supp}(f)\subseteq U\}$$For $U$ a nonempty open subset of $X$.